# Why do I not get guaranteed copy elision with std::tuple?

Tags: c++, c++20, stdtuple, copy-elision, rvo

I would expect that in C++20 the following code prints nothing between prints of A and B (since I expect guaranteed RVO to kick in). But output is:

> A
>
> Bye
>
> B
>
> C
>
> Bye
>
> Bye

So presumably one temporary is being created.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
struct INeedElision{
    int i;
    ~INeedElision(){
        std::cout << "Bye\n";
    }
};

std::tuple<int, INeedElision> f(){
    int i = 47;
    return {i, {47}};
}

INeedElision g(){
    return {};
}

int main()
{   
    std::cout << "A\n"; 
    auto x = f();
    std::cout << "B\n";
    auto y = g();
    std::cout << "C\n";
}
```

What is the reason for this behavior?
Is there a workaround to avoid copy (without using pointers)?

https://godbolt.org/z/zasoGd

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When constructing `std::tuple<int, INeedElision>` from `{i, {47}}`, [the selected constructor of `std::tuple`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tuple) takes elements by lvalue-reference to `const`.

> ```
> tuple( const Types&... args );
> ```

Then when use `{i, {47}}` as the initializer, a temporary `INeedElision` will be constructed and then passed to the constructor of `std::tuple` (and get copied). The temporary object will be destroyed immediately and you'll see "Bye" between "A" and "B".

BTW: The 3rd constructor of `std::tuple` won't be used for this case.

> ```
> template< class... UTypes >
> tuple( UTypes&&... args );
> ```

It's a constructor template, and braced-init-list like `{47}` doesn't have type and can't be deduced by template argument deduction.

On the other hand, if `INeedElision` has a converting constructor taking `int`, and make the initializer as `{i, 47}`, the 3rd constructor of `std::tuple` will be used and no temporary `INeedElision` is constructed; the element will be constructed in-place from the `int` `47`.

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/tL3yTw73cSNvF4rd)

Comment: This is not the only constructor of `std::tuple`. Is it actually the one being used in this case?

Comment: @MarkusMayr I think so. Which one are you expecting?

Comment: @songyuanyao probably same as me, some version taking && args and std::forward assigning them in constructor

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl You meant the 3rd one? No, it's a constructor template, and braced-init-list like `{47}` doesn't work with template argument deduction.

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl You might want [this](https://wandbox.org/permlink/tL3yTw73cSNvF4rd).

Comment: @songyuanyao you should probably include that in your answer :)

Comment: @songyuanyao will verify your fix and if it works accept it.

Comment: This worked, but boy is C++ horrible... adding constructor so that perfect *backwarding* will work :)

Comment: nitpick: I would open your answer with: *selected* constructor... because novice reader might assume that is the only tuple ctor...

Answer (score 1):

you only get copy elision if you return the object itself :

```
std::vector<int> fn1()
{
   return std::vector<int>{}; // guaranteed copy elision
}

std::vector<int> fn2()
{
   std::vector<int> vec;
   return vec; // a good compiler will manage to elide the copy/move here
}
```

in your case you are returning tuple so the tuple itself maybe copy elided but not the arguments passed to the constructor of the tuple !

```
std::tuple<int, INeedElision> f(){

    int i = 47;
    return {i, {47}}; // construct the tuple in place of the return address but the arguments are copied into the tuple and not even moved ! to move call std::move explicitly
}
```

the compiler isn't allowed to elide the copy of arguments passed to the tuple constructor because you aren't returning the arguments themselves but rather the tuple containing copy of them . Also note that the table can't hold references to the arguments because these local variables will have been destructed by the time the function returns resulting in a dangling references .

if you want to get a chance for copy elision in c++ 17 and later do something like this :

```
std::tuple<int, INeedElision> f(){

    std::tuple<int, INeedElision> ret;
    auto& [i, ne] = ret;
    i = 47;
    ne = 47;
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: NRVO is not guaranteed AFAIK

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl yes and I did say so